# even when getting the full script I get TypeError: $.post is not a function

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am not able to use $.post on my node.js even though it looks like. got the full script.
What else should I check?

```
var $ = require( './../../public/js/jquery-3.5.1.min' );
```

.
.
.

```
$.post( "/api/auth", function( response ) {
        return callback(response);
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you  set $ to jQuery?

Comment: Check that you haven't retrieved the *slim* version by accident - do any other jquery methods work?

Comment: No its not the slim version.

Comment: "did you set $ to jQuery? " what do you mean?